# How to search tweets efficiently with R (popular tweets first)?

Tags: r, twitter

With the package twitteR, it is possible to search tweets as follows:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("term", n=100,lang="en",resultType="recent",
                        since="2016-06-10", until="2016-06-26")
```

When the `resultType="recent"`  we can get the big number of tweets, but they are ranked with created time, so we begin with a lot of `2016-06-25 23:59:59`.

I wanted to search for popular tweets first, so I use `resultType="popular"` :

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("term", n=100,lang="en",resultType="popular",
                        since="2016-06-10", until="2016-06-26")
```

But then I got this warning :

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  100 tweets were requested but the API can only return 93
```

I understand that Twitter limit the resquests, but since they can return 100 tweets in the order of created time, I hoped that I could get the same number of tweets in the order of popularity. Apparently it is not true.

Or maybe I didn't use the function in right way.

So I would like find a way to search tweets efficiently:

- How to get more popular tweets, in a day ?
- How to specify the an hour for the search, for example 10am ? so that they are not tweeted at `2016-06-25 23:59:59`, which can have a bias.
- Maybe we have to pay, in order to get more tweets and more information ? For example, I noticed that my tweets are never geocoded.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I save them in a data.frame, after that play with # of RT's, etc... I don't think you can do it directly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe Twitter will return *the* most popular Tweets in order. Either most recent or popular (however Twitter determines it) tweets are returned. Since Twitter only returned 93 Tweets, I'd suggest you try broadening your search terms and then looking at number of favorites, retweets, replies, etc. for each tweet.